# runit and nginx

Tags: nginx, runit

I'm working on a system whose primary startup system is runit.

Unfortunately, runit requires that whatever application it is running be running in the foreground like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec sshd -D
```

Seeing as nginx doesn't offer a way to run it in the foreground, how can I have runit still manage nginx and be able to stop, start, and restart it using runit's `sv` commands?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use option `daemon off`:

```
exec /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf  -g "daemon off;"
```

From [nginx wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/MainModuleJa#daemon):

> You can use daemon off safely in production mode with runit /
>   daemontools however you can't do a graceful upgrade. master_process
>   off should never be used in production.

When you use `runit` to control `nginx`, it becomes the parent process of the `nginx` master process. But if you try to do an online upgrade, the `nginx` master process will fork and execute the new binary.

A new master process is created, but because old master process still exists (because it's controlled by `runit`), the parent of the new master process will be the init process, because `runit` can not control new master master process as it didn't start it.

Comment: Is there any way to do an online upgrade using runit? Sometimes, runit makes me miss my old simple `/etc/init.d/` scripts.

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay: `nginx` doc says you can't. My answer also provides details explanation.

Comment: What if runit becomes PID 1 inside, say a container? Then.. what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Don’t turn off the master process for anything used in the real world, it doesn’t do zero-downtime upgrades and it’s unsupported.

Do it the/a right way using page sentinel monitoring of port 80, etc. to not contain some magic content, otherwise nginx can’t do zero-downtime upgrades and you’ll look like a rank amateur.

```
# . . .
set -e
## config - start - should move to another file
CONF='/etc/nginx/nginx.conf'
# TODO: grab below by parsing CONF
PROTO=http
IP=0.0.0.0
PORT=80
## config - end - should move to another file
case "$(uname | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')" in
darwin|freebsd|netbsd|openbsd) NC_ARGS="-n -w 5 -z '${IP}' '${PORT}'" ;;
linux) NC_ARGS="-n -w 5 --send-only '${IP}' '${PORT}'" ;;
*) echo "unsupported os $(uname)" >&2; exit 1 ;;
esac
/usr/bin/nginx -t -c "${CONF}"
/usr/bin/nginx -c "${CONF}"
sleep 5
while /usr/bin/nc $NC_ARGS </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1; do
  set -e # loop runs in a subshell
  /usr/bin/curl -m5 -fsS -A 'runit script/0.0.0' \
    "${PROTO}"://"${IP}":"${PORT}" | \
    /usr/bin/grep -q 'This comment is required'
  sleep 2
done
```